# Switching flutter font based on app Locale

Tags: flutter

So im making an app that displays flight information in 3 languages. it updates the page every minute, changing the language. i want the font to change with the locale of the app.

ive looked up solutions like the following:
getting the locale of the app and setting the font in an IF block, but im getting the error:

`Requested the Locale of a context that does not include a Localizations ancestor. To request the Locale, the context used to retrieve the Localizations widget must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Localizations widget.`

```
class Main extends StatefulWidget {
  const Main({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainState createState() => _MainState();
}

class _MainState extends State<Main> {
  VoidCallback rebuildOnLocaleChange() => () => setState(() {});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // String locale = Platform.localeName.split('_')[0];
    Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: myLocale == Locale("fa")
              ? "IRANSans"
              : myLocale == Locale("ar")
                  ? "Baloo"
                  : "open-sans",
          useMaterial3: true,
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en'),
        Locale('fa'),
        Locale('ar'),
      ],
      locale: const Locale("en"),
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

one thing that has worked for me is introducing a locale variable and then using that. like so:

```
class _MainState extends State<Main> {
  VoidCallback rebuildOnLocaleChange() => () => setState(() {});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String myLocale = "ar";
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: myLocale == "fa"
              ? "IRANSans"
              : myLocale == "ar"
                  ? "Baloo"
                  : "open-sans",
          useMaterial3: true,
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en'),
        Locale('fa'),
        Locale('ar'),
      ],
      locale: Locale(myLocale),
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**but im wondering if there is a better way to do this.
also im still learning flutter and dont know how to change that variable later on... :)**